# Remove gpkg delated QGIS

Tags: qgis, error, geopackage, connection, remove

I accidentally deleted a gpkg file from QGIS browser… I thought it was to delete the connection and the file was deleted… does anyone know any way to recover it? Does QGIS save deleted files somewhere?

Comment: Have a look at the recycle bin of your system. Normally, this is more of a question on the level of the operating system than the application you use. Files are hardly deleted at all, only intentionally overwriting them with random data really comes close to delete. So there are high chances you can recover your file(s). Search for "recover deleted files" for your Operating system.

Comment: My QGIS browser GeoPackage section lists geopackages with right-click options: "Remove Connection" and "Delete FOO.gpkg...".  The delete option asks if I'm sure I want to "delete /the/path/to/FOO.gpkg". If you deleted the file without it being clear it was the file being deleted, I'd file an issue with QGIS to clarify. Was it a poorly translated text? Personally I'm not sure something as dangerous as "delete" should be there.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think QGIS saves a backup copy. If you are on a windows system you could try using the Recuva software, it's pretty straightforward.